# How kafka consumer works if consumers are more that partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

Could anyone please explain and direct me link or resource to read about how the kafka consumers works in below scenarios.

1. 1 consumer-group with 5 consumers and 1 topic with 3 partitions (how kafka decides )
2. 1 Consumer-group with 5 consumers and 1 topic with 10 partitions ( how kafka share load)
3. 2 consumer-groups with 1 consumer each and kafka cluster of 2 servers where one topic is partitioned between node 1 and node 2 , how duplications can be avoided when consumers from different groups subscribed to one partition.

The above may not a best practice when configuring kafka , but i need to know how it handled.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

It's not Kafka itself to assign partitions, but one of the consumers.
The first one joining a consumer group will be elected as sort of "leader" and we'll start assigning partitions to the other consumers.
Of course, every time a new consumer joins the group, the Kafka "controller" let the leader consumer to know about that and it starts the rebalancing re-assigning partitions. It's the same when a consumer leaves a consumer group.

To confirm that the consumer is involved on that, the strategy for partition assignment is specified by the `partition.assignment.strategy` property in a consumer configuration. The default value is `RangeAssignor` while the other ones are `RoundRobinAssignor` and `StickyAssignor`.
You can find more about how they work here:

https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html
https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RoundRobinAssignor.html
https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html

Said that, what happens specifically in your scenarios?

1. 3 consumers will get one partition each. The other 2 will be idle.
2. each consumer will get 2 partitions
3. Using different consumer groups mean pure pub/sub where the consumer groups get same messages. In your case with 1 topic and 2 partitions (on 2 brokers), the two consumers each in one different consumer group, will get the same messages from all 2 partitions. If consumers are part of different consumer groups you cannot avoid duplication, it's how Kafka works.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer this question in agile way.

> 1. 1 consumer-group with 5 consumers and 1 topic with 3 partitions

consumers will not get any work with more consumers than partitions. Here you have more consumer then partition.
[image]

Why might you be okay with that? In some instances, you might want to make sure that a similar rate of consumption occurs if a consumer dies unexpectedly (like network latency concerns or a cluster that stretches across data centres).

> 2. 1 Consumer-groups with 5 consumers and 1 topic with 10 partitions ( how kafka share load)

consumers handle more than one partition if needed.
[image]

**Note:** As a general rule, only one consumer per consumer group can read one partition. In other words, whereas a partition might be read by many consumers, it can only be read by one consumer from each group at a time.

> 3. 2 consumer-groups with 1 consumer each and kafka cluster of 2 servers where one topic is partitioned between node 1 and node 2 , how duplications can be avoided when consumers from different groups subscribed to one partition.

Your question itself has your answer. Once you keep your consumer under consumer group this is where the duplication removed.

*Let’s think of two use cases for data that come from a human resource system (or HR system).*
One team wonders about the number of hires from specific states and other team is more interested in the data for the impact on travel budgets for interviews.
Would anyone on the first team care about what the other team is doing or would either of the teams want to consume only a portion of the messages? Likely not! Right

> How can we keep this separation?

The answer is to assign a separate consumer group to each application.

Each department (the Hiring Department and the Travel Department) forms its own separate "consumer group" with a unique group ID.

The Hiring Department's consumer group gets one copy of the messages from the HR topic.
The Travel Department's consumer group gets another copy of the same messages from the HR topic.

This way, the two consumer groups operate independently, without interfering with each other. They can consume the messages at their own pace, focus on the parts they care about, and not worry about what the other group is doing.

If both teams used the same group ID, they would be part of the same consumer group and would have to share and coordinate the message consumption, which is not desirable in this case.

Comment: This is an extremely high-quality answer. I wish all StackExchange answers were like this!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on `partition.assignment.strategy` property, which is set to the class *org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor* bu default. From the java doc:

> The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. For each topic, we lay out the available partitions in numeric order and the consumers in lexicographic order. We then divide the number of partitions by the total number of consumers to determine the number of partitions to assign to each consumer. If it does not evenly divide, then the first few consumers will have one extra partition. For example, suppose there are two consumers C0 and C1, two topics t0 and t1, and each topic has 3 partitions, resulting in partitions t0p0, t0p1, t0p2, t1p0, t1p1, and t1p2. The assignment will be: C0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1] C1: [t0p2, t1p2]

You can provide your own strategy by implementing *org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.PartitionAssignor*.
There is a [good article](https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab) on Medium about it.